# Why is XeTeX's quotation mark ligature suppressed?

Tags: fonts, xetex, ligatures, xecjk

Compile this with xetex

```
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\XeTeXcharclass `' = 5
\XeTeXinterchartoks 5 3={\empty}
''。\par
\XeTeXinterchartoks 5 3={}
''。\par
\bye
```

will get

[image].

An empty macro disables the ligatue, but in xelatex

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\XeTeXcharclass `' = 5
\XeTeXinterchartoks 5 3={\empty}
''。\par
\XeTeXinterchartoks 5 3={}
''。\par
\end{document}
```

then I get the correct quotation mark.

[image]

Comment: I know it's lmroman, but why does cmr have the first ligatue but not the other?

Comment: Legacy fonts are treated differently from OpenType ones. In the XeLaTeX example the ligature is formed before the next character `。` is examined, due to `mapping=tex-text`.